# how to android fcm default channel in app?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

Once I saw this error, I googled enough and realized it was a manifest meta data problem, so I asked the question after fixing it and doing a lot of work.

ex) manifest
default_notification_channel -> default_notification_channel_id

my log cat

```
2021-08-15 14:03:05.326 26315-27157/com.project W/FirebaseMessaging: Notification Channel requested (fcm_default_channel) has not been created by the app. Manifest configuration, or default, value will be used.
2021-08-15 14:03:05.327 26315-27157/com.project W/FirebaseMessaging: Notification Channel set in AndroidManifest.xml has not been created by the app. Default value will be used.
```

my manifest

```
 <service
            android:name=".ui.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

and my fcm service class

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        Timber.d("Refreshed token: $token")

        //TODO : Token save 

    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        
        Timber.d("MyFirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived 성공!!!!")
        
        if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {
            Timber.d("MyFirebaseMessagingService noti.body = ${remoteMessage.notification?.body}")
            sendNotification(remoteMessage)
        }

        if (remoteMessage.data.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    }

    private fun sendNotification(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        val uniId: Int = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 7).toInt()
        
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, uniId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)

        val soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) 
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.data["body"].toString())
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.data["title"].toString())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri) 
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent) 

        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val channel =
                NotificationChannel(channelId, "Notice", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        
        notificationManager.notify(uniId, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm asking this question because fcm doesn't work properly while I'm working on saving data to room. The push message is coming, but the data is not logged and I am not sure if the correct data is coming because such an error is coming out.

I haven't been able to solve this problem, can you help me yet?